# generate output from php array

Tags: php, arrays, operations

i'm trying to generate a firewall template from a php config

i've got this array

```
$config=array('1024','3306','3804','127017');
```

and i would like this output

```
1024:3305
3307:3803
3805:127017
```

as you can see, the first and last value stay the same, the value in between are -1 / +1

i think i can do it but not in a clean way, 
i tried to manipulate the array but in a wrong way i guess because the code is too verbose

may you help ?

thanks

Comment: Can you please show us your code , that you have tried ?

Comment: Do you want your output as a string or as a new array?

Comment: for now i've got nothing to show sorry... @tommy as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$config=array('1024','3306','3804','127017');

$output = [];

foreach ($config as $k => $port) {
    if (isset($config[$k+1])) {
        $output[] = ($k ? $port + 1 : $port)
            . ':'
            . (isset($config[$k+2]) ? ($config[$k + 1] - 1) : $config[$k + 1]);
    }
}

echo implode("<br>", $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$config=array('1024','3306','3804','127017');

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($config); $i++) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        echo $config[$i] . ":";
    } elseif($i == (sizeof($config)-1)) {
        echo $config[$i];
    } else {
        echo ($config[$i]-1)."<br />".($config[$i]+1).":";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend storing the values in an associative array first so that you can use this data for further operations. Output it in a second step:

```
$config = ['1024','3306','3804','127017'];

$result = [];
for ($i = 0, $count = count($config) - 2; $i <= $count; ++$i)
{
    $key = $i == 0 ? $config[$i] : $config[$i] + 1;
    $value = $i == 0
        ? $config[$i + 1] - 1
        : (
            $i == $count ? $config[$i + 1] : $config[$i + 1] - 1
        );
    $result[$key] = $value;
}

// Output it:
foreach ($result as $key => $value)
{
    echo "$key:$value <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
<?php 
$config=array('1024','3306','3804','127017');

$c = count($config);
for ($n = 0; $n<$c-1; $n++) {
    printf(
        '%d:%d'.PHP_EOL,
        ($n==0 ? $config[0] : $config[$n]+1),        // use incremented value if not first
        ($n==$c-2 ? $config[$c-1] : $config[$n+1]-1) // use decremented value if not last
    );
}
```

If you want to output to the browser, you will have to add a `<br>` tag in the `printf()` template.

[See it in action.](https://eval.in/483479)